# Read all files in a nested folder in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

If we have a folder `folder` having all `.txt` files, we can read them all using `sc.textFile("folder/*.txt")`. But what if I have a folder `folder` containing even more folders named datewise, like, `03`, `04`, ..., which further contain some `.log` files. How do I read these in Spark?

In my case, the structure is even more nested & complex, so a general answer is preferred.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If directory structure is regular, lets say something like this:

```
folder
├── a
│   ├── a
│   │   └── aa.txt
│   └── b
│       └── ab.txt
└── b
    ├── a
    │   └── ba.txt
    └── b
        └── bb.txt
```

you can use `*` wildcard for each level of nesting as shown below:

```
>>> sc.wholeTextFiles("/folder/*/*/*.txt").map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

[u'file:/folder/a/a/aa.txt',
 u'file:/folder/a/b/ab.txt',
 u'file:/folder/b/a/ba.txt',
 u'file:/folder/b/b/bb.txt']
```

Comment: This solved my particular issue. Btw, what if the directory structure is not regular?

Comment: Then things  start getting messy :) Idea is more or less the same  but it is unlikely you can prepare patterns that can be easily reused. You can always you normal tools to traverse filesystem and collect paths instead of hardcoding.

Comment: Why does this not work with `/folder/**/*.txt`? I have basically the exact same directory structure and I'd like to open all with `sc.wholeTextFiles('data/**/*.json')` but that does not seem to work ..?

Comment: @zero323, I couldn't use the whilecard in wholetextfile as getting the error llegalArgumentException: 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index.

Comment: In this case, since all of the files under the "a" directory are .txt, the last /*.txt is unnecessary.

Answer (score 36):

Spark 3.0 provides an option **recursiveFileLookup** to load files from recursive subfolders.

```
val df = SparkSession.read
       .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
       .option("header", "true")
       .csv("src/main/resources/nested")
```

This recursively loads the files from `src/main/resources/nested` and it's subfolders.

Answer (score 6):

if you want use only files which start with name "a" ,you can use

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("/folder/a*/*/*.txt") or sc.wholeTextFiles("/folder/a*/a*/*.txt")
```

as well. We can use * as wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

`sc.wholeTextFiles("/directory/201910*/part-*.lzo")` get all match files **name**, not files content.

if you want to load the contents of all matched files in a directory, you should use

```py
sc.textFile("/directory/201910*/part-*.lzo")
```

and setting reading directory recursive!

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")
```

**TIPS:** scala differ with python, below set use to scala!

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")
```