# How can i read all parquet files from all subfolder

Tags: scala, apache-spark

folder achitecture:

```
dir1
 |-dir1-1
 |    |-file1.parquet
 |-dir1-2
     |-file2.parquet
```

how can i read all parquet files, i try to use

```
sparkSession.read.format("parquet")
      .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
      .load("dir1path")
```

but it shows error: unable to infer schema for parquet. it must be specified manully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all files in a nested folder in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233575/read-all-files-in-a-nested-folder-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

my current solution is: `sparkSession.read.parquet("dir1/*")`