# how to read data from multiple folder from adls to databricks dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks, pyspark-pandas

file path format is data/year/weeknumber/no of day/data_hour.parquet

data/2022/05/01/00/data_00.parquet

data/2022/05/01/01/data_01.parquet

data/2022/05/01/02/data_02.parquet

data/2022/05/01/03/data_03.parquet

data/2022/05/01/04/data_04.parquet

data/2022/05/01/05/data_05.parquet

data/2022/05/01/06/data_06.parquet

data/2022/05/01/07/data_07.parquet

how to read all this file one by one in data bricks notebook and store into the data frame

```
import pandas as pd 

#Get all the files under the folder
data = dbutils.fs.la(file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Create the list of file
list = df.path.tolist()

    enter code here

for i in list:
    df = spark.read.load(path=f'{f}*',format='parquet')
```

i can able to read only the last file skipping the other file

Comment: Hi, at least, share some your codes that you have been trying and failed. Anyway, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233865) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: please find the above code which i am using, was looking for parquet files not for .txt

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code cannot load data incrementally. In contrast, it refreshes df variable with the data from each path for each time it ran.

Removing the for loop and trying the code below would give you an idea how file masking with asterisks works. Note that the path should be a full path. (I'm not sure if the data folder is your root folder or not)

```python
df = spark.read.load(path='/data/2022/05/*/*/*.parquet',format='parquet')
```

This is what I have applied from the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233865) I shared with you in the comment.

Comment: days = list["2020/05/06","2020/05/07","2020/05/08","2020/05/09","2020/05/10"]  (yy/mm/dd)             
I need to read the data from folder mention only in the list

Comment: days = List['2022/05/06/*/*','2022/05/07/*/*']                                                                   
paths = days.map(day => "data/"  ++day)                df=spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths)                                                                      I try this but it didn't work

Comment: Got it.  So you can leave the for loop and apply this code instead `df = df.union(spark.read.load(path=f'{i}',format='parquet'))` ...Kindly accept my answer if this works, Thanks.

Comment: How come you got this error "df not defined" after this line `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` ?