# How to combine multiple CSV files into one file if the column seq is different or some the files are not having any header

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, directory, nested

For example i have over 300 files in the nested folder and i have combine all of them using pyspark or python pandas

File1 -Date,channel,spend,clicks
File2 - date ,channel,clicks,spend
File3- no
File4 : some extra columns also there apart from mandatory ones
Etc...
Etc

I am expecting a single file combining all the files in folder with different structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce the schema object to take care of files with no headers and unify the structure using `spark.read.schema(ScheamObject).csv(FilesPath)`.
You can use `coalesce(1)` in writing out to fit all records into one file: `spark.write.coalesce(1).csv(DestinationPath)`

Comment: Thank you ,but How to loop through the files reading from gcp folders and display those file columns in each file

Comment: You can use regular expressions in your file read path. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233575/read-all-files-in-a-nested-folder-in-spark